# connection timed out error while deploying spring app

Tags: java, ms-access, spring, jdbc, spring-mvc

I’m trying to deploy a simple Spring app  and getting a “connection timed out ” error. My app tries to take a text input from the user in one jsp, insert that value under username in the db and then display that name in another jsp along with a greeting eg: "hello, "

My environment:

1. OS: Windows XP professional
2. Server : Tomcat 6
3. IDE: Eclipse
4. DB: MS Access 2007

I am getting the error below:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from
>   ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml];
>   nested exception is
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333) 
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:520)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:470)
>         at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:231)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:304)
>         at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
>
> SEVERE: Servlet /SpringExample threw
>   load() exception
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:520)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:470)
>         at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:157)

The code to access the db is as below:

//in the profile.java class

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
              int rowsInserted;
              setDataSource(dataSource);
             jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
             rowsInserted = jt.update("insert into usernamedb (username) values(?)",new Object[] { username });
             System.out.println(rowsInserted);
             }
```

in the profileFormController.java class

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command)
    {
        Profile profile = (Profile) command; 
        String greeting = "Hello," + profile.getUsername() + "!";
        //System.out.println(greeting);
        profile.setUsername(profile.getUsername());
        return new ModelAndView("greetingDisplay", "greeting", greeting);
    }
```

To set up the DNS, in the ODBC sources I have set “usernamedb” as a DNS source by the user. I am not able to figure out the root cause for this error.

Comment: applicationContext.xml:

<bean id="profile" class= "SpringExample.Profile">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean> 
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" scope="singleton" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName" value="sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:odbc:usernamedb" />
<property name="username" value="admin" />
<property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

Comment: can you ping usernamedb?

Comment: Sorry, didnt get your question. How can I ping the db? Secondly, I tried running the program without the DB connecivity and thats giving the same error as well.

Comment: I mean "the host where usernamedb" resides. but it's probably localhost. Give the whole spring config, by editing your question.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the DB/JDBC code. The problem is in parsing the spring XML file. It is trying to download something from the internet over HTTP, but failed because the HTTP connection timed out. Please edit your question to remove the irrelevant DB code and post the `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` along with the **entire** stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check to see if your db server is running.  If it is, make sure you are trying to connect to it at the right address at the right port number, and if you are giving it the right username and password.

If all of those seem to be working you may also need to check that your db server will accept connections from the your address.

Comment: The stacktrace tells that it failed to parse the `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` file and all the DB interaction is far beyond this and can thus not be the root cause of this all. The OP made the mistake to only read the message "connection timed out" instead of the entire trace.

Answer (score 0):

In case, any one is still looking for a resolution, take a look at the DTD definition in your /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml  including the dtd version

If you can't find anything wrong, try moving to the XML Schema style of configuration.   Please see  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body